# Dope sheet playhead (time scrubber) does not move while animation is playing

Tags: animation, interface

Using Blender 3.5.0.

Within my timeline window, I have option Playback->"Play In"->"Animation Editors" turned on (checkbox checked, the default).

If various animation windows like the dope sheet are open within the main Blender window, the current time "cursor" (playhead) in the dope sheet moves along with (is sync'd with) the cursor in the timeline window while the animation plays (as expected).

However, if dope sheet was opened as an independent window (shift+LMB), detached from the main Blender window, the dope sheet's playhead position does not move while the animation is playing.

Is there a setting to make this happen, or is this a bug?

TIA!!!

Comment: having the same issue on a dual monitor setup, find a solution?